# Do you have to keep Bluetooth on to scan for Bluetooth Low Energy devices?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

When using advertise-only non-connectable Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy / Smart devices like heart rate monitors, do you have to keep / turn Bluetooth switch on in your iPhone / iPad?

I believe the energy drain is negligible, but the need to and explicitly turn on BT may be really frustrating for some applications.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer would be YES. The BT has to be on to scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to activate Bluetooth on any iOS device in order for it to interact with other Bluetooth devices, including LE ones.

iOS7 will add a lot of nice compatibility to BT LE devices but it looks as though even with that you will still have to turn on Bluetooth.

Source: http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/13/apple-unlocks-full-notification-center-access-much-more-for-bluetooth-le-devices-in-ios-7/